# Gradle Tomcat plugin set JVM arguments

Tags: tomcat, gradle, jvm-arguments, gradle-tomcat-plugin

I am using Gradle Tomcat plugin and wanting to set JVM arguments like: "-javaagent:/home/blablabla.jar" to "tomcatRun" tasks. I am using Gradle 2.4. I tried many examples , but failed. What is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedded Tomcat container runs in the same JVM process as Gradle. You'll have to provide your JVM arguments when starting the Gradle process. You could probably just add it to the environment variable `GRADLE_OPTS`. What is it your are specifically trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add spring threading agent: "-javaagent:/home/killer/jars/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar" Also would be nice to add it only for a particular task rather than export a variable to environment.

Comment: Not possible at the moment. For that the implementation would need to create a forked process that runs Tomcat. Contributions welcome!